# specifying pyvenv in projects .dir-locals.el

Tags: virtualenv

I'm trying to use `.dir-locals.el` within porjects to specify the Python virtualenv that is activated on a per project basis using [pyvenv](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/pyvenv).  I've read the examples at [Directory Variables - GNU Emacs Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html) and have tried

```
((python-mode . ((pyvenv-workon "~/.virtualenvs/default")
         (subdirs . nil))))
```

With this I get the following error...

```
File local-variables error: (wrong-type-argument stringp (~/virtualenvs/default)
```

...and it does  not activate this virtual environment, instead its activating `anaconda3` which is a nuisance because I thought I'd purged my system of Anaconda (in favour of using virtualenvwrapper).

I have the following in `~/.emacs.d/settings/python-settings.el` (which is called from `~/.emacs.d/init.el`)

```
;; elpy configuration
(elpy-enable)
(pyvenv-activate "~/.virtualenvs/dskit")

;; Set ipython as the default interpreter
(setq elpy-rpc-python-command "python3")
(setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython"
      python-shell-interpreter-args "-i --simple-prompt")
```

...and as I say I've purged my system of anaconda so I'm not sure how or why its being picked up as a virtual environment.  Is there anyway to get debugging information out of Emacs pyvenv module when its loading to find out what its doing co I can work out whats going on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the confusing things about `.dir-locals.el` variables is that the bindings need to be conses, usually written in dotted form:

```
((python-mode . ((pyvenv-workon . "~/.virtualenvs/default")
                 (subdirs . nil))))
```

Without the ., lisp interprets the second part of the pair as a list, so (in this case), your configuration was saying that the value of `pyvenv-workon` was the list `("~/.virtualenvs/default")` instead of just the string, which is what the `wrong-type-argument` error is saying. If the bit about `cons` is unfamiliar, you might take a look at [cons](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/cons.html) in the Emacs Lisp manual.

Comment: Thank you @Win that has done the trick.  Slowly learning more Lisp as I get more into using Emacs for my IDE and all other aspects of my work on computers.

Comment: For some reason this makes my Python buffer extremely laggy - I have `(setenv "WORKON_HOME" "~/<<directory where envs are stored>>"))` in my config, and putting `((python-mode . ((eval . (pyvenv-workon "<<env name>>")))))` in `.dir-locals.el` fixed it for me.